# List of figures/tables does not appear in header, what's in header is last chapter's name

Tags: header-footer, titletoc

I have a document (see example below) with 2 parts, each part has a list of figures and list of tables that are listed in the part's contents as well as in the global content.
But when looking at the page listing the figures p.13 and 29 (or the tables p.15 or 31), I see in the header "Chapter 1. Some chapter" instead of "List of figures" or "list of tables".

How can I put in the header "List of figures" or "list of tables" instead?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{{\chaptername}\ \thechapter.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.1pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.1pt}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
  \fancyfoot[C]{}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{Contents}{}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\startcontents[parts]
\startlist[mylof]{lof}
\startlist[mylot]{lot}

\part{A part}
\chapter*{Contents}
\printcontents[parts]{}{-1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}

\chapter{Some chapter}

% create a bunch of items to fill pages in the lists of tables and figures
\def\z{
  \begin{figure}[htp]
  \caption{A}
  \end{figure}
  zz
  \begin{table}[htp]
  \caption{B}
  \end{table}
  zz
}
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z

% \phantomsection
% \listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
\printlist[mylof]{lof}{0}{\chapter*{List of figures}}
% \listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of tables}
\printlist[mylot]{lot}{0}{\chapter*{List of tables}}


\stoplist[mylof]{lof}
\stoplist[mylot]{lot}
\stopcontents[parts]

\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\startcontents[parts]
\startlist[mylof2]{lof}
\startlist[mylot2]{lot}

\part{A other part}
\chapter*{Contents}
\printcontents[parts]{}{-1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}

\chapter{Some chapter}

% create a bunch of items to fill pages in the lists of tables and figures
\def\z{
  \begin{figure}[htp]
  \caption{A}
  \end{figure}
  zz
  \begin{table}[htp]
  \caption{B}
  \end{table}
  zz
}
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z

% \phantomsection
% \listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
\printlist[mylof2]{lof}{0}{\chapter*{List of figures}}
% \listoftables
\printlist[mylot2]{lot}{0}{\chapter*{List of tables}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of tables}


\stoplist[mylof2]{lof}
\stoplist[mylot2]{lot}
\stopcontents[parts]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\markright{Lof}` or `\markleft{Lof}` (or `\markboth{Lof}{Lof}`) according to your needs.

Comment: You should put that right where you print the list (e.g. after `\addcontentsline`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following code solves your problem:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
\printlist[mylof2]{lof}{0}{\chapter*{List of figures}\markboth{List of Figures}{List of Figures}}
% \listoftables
\printlist[mylot2]{lot}{0}{\chapter*{List of tables}\markboth{List of Tables}{List of Tables}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of tables}
```